# Matriz en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrices

Se desea crear una matriz A de tamaño n*n inicialmente llena de ceros. Se pide por teclado las dimensiones de esta matriz, luego deben cambiarse n elementos de la matriz por "B" estos elementos son cambiados por el usuario.
Por ejemplo para n=3 se tiene

`A= [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]`

Si se desean cambiar, por ejemplo, los siguientes elementos

```
A[0][0], A[1][2], A[2][2]
```

Por "B". Debería tenerse la matriz

```
A=[["B",0,0],[0,0,"B"],[0,0,"B"]]
```

El código que estoy implementando es

```
 def crea_matriz(n):
    matriz=[]
    for i in range(n):
        a=[0]*n
        matriz.append(a)
    return matriz
n=int(input("Intruzca la dimension de la matriz:")) 
A=crea_matriz(n)
for i in range(n):
    a=int(input("Fila cambia:"))
for j in range(n):  
    b=int(input("Columna cambia:"))
A[a][b]="B"
print(A)
```

Al aplicarlo obtengo la matriz

```
A=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,"B"]]
```

Es decir que solamente está cambiando el último elemento que deseo cambiar.
¿Cómo podría obtener lo que requiero? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en los bucles for cuando pides la fila y la columna. Cuando te pide que introduzca la fila, el valor se almacena en la variable a, sin embargo, la siguiente vez que pides la fila reemplazas el valor anterior por el nuevo valor. Por tanto, al acabar la iteración te quedas con el último valor, igual pasa cuando pides la columna.

Esta es la solución que te propongo, he puesto un bucle infinito para pedir todas las modificaciones que tu deseas, y para salir simplemente debes presionar la tecla enter sin  introducir ningún valor. Tengo que destacar que no existe ningún tipo de control en la entrada del usuario, esto puede generar problemas.

```
def crea_matriz(n):
    matriz=[]
    for i in range(n):
        a=[0]*n
        matriz.append(a)
    return matriz
n=int(input("Intruzca la dimension de la matriz:")) 
A=crea_matriz(n)
while True:
    a = input("Fila cambia:")
    if not a:
        break

    b = input("Columna cambia:")
    if not b:
       break
    A[int(a)][int(b)]="B"
print(A)
```